# Angular2+ grey out mat rows under specific condition

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, tablerow, mat-table

im very new to Angular. I have a component which creats dynamicly mat tables from a datasource. I want that some of the mat rows get greyd out or something else (show the row but with no data in it) when a specific condition compared to a part of the datasource is true or false.

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you some sample mat-table from material.angular.io

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

As you can see in penultimate line of code you have defined `<tr>` with `row` element.
So if you want to grey out whole row you have to add to it some dynamic-class like that:

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [class.disabled]="row.disabled"></tr>
```

As you can see I use `disabled` attribute from object passed to each row.